# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in for loop on 2d array

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, undefined

For the below javascript code

```
function hasSpecialColumn(arr) {
  for (let col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {

      let sumOfOnes = 0;

      for (let row = 0; row < arr.length; arr++) {
          if (arr[row][col] === 1) {
              sumOfOnes++;
              if (sumOfOnes >= 2) {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }

  }
  return false;
}

const arr = [[3,4],[5,6]];
console.log(hasSpecialColumn(arr));
```

I'm getting the following error with nodejs.

```
 Users/khaymahd/workspace/iv/for-loop-undefined-error.js:3
      for (let col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
                                    ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at hasSpecialColumn (/Users/khaymahd/workspace/iv/for-loop-undefined-error.js:3:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/khaymahd/workspace/iv/for-loop-undefined-error.js:21:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Also tried in chrome console

```
VM183:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at hasSpecialColumn (<anonymous>:3:38)
    at <anonymous>:21:17
```

It is a weird error! However, If I set size = arr[0].length and use that in the for loop it works. but I don't I understand why the original code does not work.

Comment: You are overwriting your array in this line: `for (let row = 0; row < arr.length; arr++) ` That should be `row++`. When you do this `arr` becomes `NaN` and on the next iteration of the loop it tries to access `NaN[0]` which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like it thinks arr[0] is undefined, try putting `console.log(arr);` and `console.log(arr[0])`. One of those probably will return undefined, which is causing your current error.